# Defining one macro two values on different target in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an application having two target, I want to define a macro having different value for different target.how can i do that? both are release version

Comment: Refer: http://www.codeworth.com/blog/mobile/ios-distinguish-between-targets-using-pre-processor-targets/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each target has it's own "Build settings" in Xcode, there you have the "Preprocessing"-category (Look for where 'DEBUG=1' is defined) where you can set custom macros that will be unique for the target.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way

```
#define CONSOLE_DEBUG 1 // Comment this line to undefine

#ifdef CONSOLE_DEBUG
     #define SMLog(format, ...) NSLog((@"%s (%d) " format), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
     #define SMLog(format, ...)
#endif
```

When you'll define  CONSOLE_DEBUG then SMLOG will print log with Pretty function. else if you comment above line then it'll just print a simple NSLOG.

You can simple check for target Macros instead of CONSOLE_DEBUG.

**EDIT:**

In one of my apps I needed to give diffent URLs so Idid it with diffrent targets as follows

```
#ifdef APP_LIVE

    #define strDefaultURL <Some URL String>
    #define strIndexPlistURL <Some URL String>

#elif APP_DEV

    #define strDefaultURL <Some URL String>
    #define strIndexPlistURL <Some URL String>

#else

    #define strDefaultURL <Some URL String>
    #define strIndexPlistURL <Some URL String>

#endif
```

Where APP_LIVE and APP_DEV were defined in respective targets.

Comment: But i have a problem that i am using this macro more than 200 times and this is not possible for me to apply this

Comment: But bro Your want only one diffrent value for each target. Doesn't matter if you use it thousand time or just one time its value will remain same. For example if I have two diffrent targets in my project like APP_DEV and APP_Production and I have a MACRO with diffrent values for both targets, as I explained in my answer, then its value willl remain same for that target. Do you want different values of MACRO each time you use it?

Comment: Is there any option to do this through plist?

Comment: @ShreeshGarg Can you tell me in detail what exactly you want? A liitle scenario of your implementation? May be I can help you better then.